# Ошибка: Каталог не обнаружен 1с

Tags: 1с

Я хочу запускать обработку по расписанию, запускаю обработку и выдает ошибку: Каталог не обнаружен "C:\1Ctest\vigruzka\output.csv". Буква С на английском.

```
Функция ВыполнитьКоманду(ИдентификаторКоманды, ПараметрыКоманды) Экспорт
    Если ИдентификаторКоманды = "Выгрузка" Тогда

        ТекстJSON = ПолучитьОстатки();

        Текст2 = Новый ЗаписьТекста("C:\1Ctest\vigruzka\output2.csv", 
        КодировкаТекста.UTF8,,ложь);
        Текст2.ЗаписатьСтроку(ТекстJSON2);
        Текст2.Закрыть();


    КонецЕсли;
КонецФункции
```

Comment: А в `1C` не нужно бэкслэши экранировать? Ну, то есть двойные писать. Да, и каталог то этот есть, куда вы файл хотите записать, а то может его правда нет и нужно создать?

Comment: Нигде не написано, какие формы обычные или управляемые, клиент толстый или тонкий, база файловая или серверная, самая распространенная ошибка, команда выполняется на сервере, а там такого пути нет.

Comment: Управляемые формы, тонкий клиент, база серверная

Comment: Так если идет сохранение на сервер, как мне изменить, что-бы сохраняло в мой каталог, который существует?

Comment: @Anton Самый простой вариант - открыть сетевой доступ к вашей папке, и в обработке прописать полный сетевой путь к ней. Другие варианты потребуют переделки обработки.

Comment: @kio Дал доступ к папке, прописал полный сетевой путь (\\192.168.0.1\1Ctest\vigruzka\output2.csv) и выдало ошибку при выполнении файловой операции

Comment: @Anton Сложно сказать в чем может быть дело. Возможно нет доступа к каталогу у УЗ под которой запущена служба 1с.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда сис. админ создал папку на сервере и дал к ней доступ для всех пользователей (для конкретного пользователя не работает), файлы добавились в папку.